# What is an elegant way to perform Bitwise operation on a list of binaries in Python?

Tags: python, binary, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit

Suppose I have a list of binaries as follows:

```
b = [0b10,0b110,0b101]
```

I want to perform bitwise AND only all the binaries in list b. Is there a more elegant way to do this rather than sequentially adding two binaries?

Comment: Is your list of *strings*, or of *integers*? There's no built-in binary type in Python.

Comment: @jonrsharpe but you can initialize integers with a binary specifier. OP has shown a perfectly legal initializer.

Comment: you can perform bitwise AND with `&`, ie `0b10&0b110 == 2` and `bin(2) == '0b10'`

Comment: @jonrsharpe I think 0b... is another way of representing integers in python. So just see them as integers.

Comment: @Zhongjun'Mark'Jin yes, binary integer literals are fine, but that's not what you would see if you printed a list created like that (as the default representation is binary); just trying to avoid any confusion.

Comment: @tdelaney I'm well aware of that and just trying to clarify *"list of binaries"*.

Comment: @jonrsharpe You are totally correct. Thanks for clarification!

Comment: How about `reduce(lambda x, y: x&y, b)`?

Comment: @rodion Great! This also works. Thanks, rodion!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `operator` standard module

```
import operator
result = reduce(operator.and_, b)
```

Comment: Cool! This is exactly what I am hoping for.

Comment: Any particular reason you picked `iand` instead of `and_`?

Comment: @user2357112: a mistake... correct is `and_` (even if for numbers it's the same)